# My highscore doesn't match my points at sometimes

Tags: c#, if-statement, for-loop, monogame, pong

When I get my points(poang) to highscore when I hit the blocks with 5 points. They will not update the same, sometimes points(poang) will be 18 and highscore will be 20.

(Sorry about my bad english)

- poang = points
- linje = line
- liv = lives
- boll = ball
- poang = points
- blockröd = blockred
- blockgrön = blockgreen

  ```
  public class Game1 : Game
  {
   GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
   SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
   SpriteFont spritefont;
   Texture2D linje_texture;
   Texture2D linjeliten_texture;
   Texture2D boll_texture;
   Texture2D blockröd_texture;
   Texture2D blockgrön_texture;
   Texture2D gameover_texture;
   Rectangle linje_rect;
   Rectangle linjeliten_rect;
   Rectangle boll_rect;
   Rectangle blockröd_rect;
   Rectangle blockgrön_rect;
   Rectangle gameover_rect;

   Vector2 linje_speed;
   Vector2 linjeliten_speed;
   Vector2 boll_speed;

   Random random;

   StreamReader sr;
   StreamWriter sw;

   int liv = 3;
   int poang = 0;
   int highscore;

   List<Rectangle> block = new List<Rectangle>();
   List<Rectangle> block2 = new List<Rectangle>();

   bool Start = false;
   bool holdingleft = false;
   bool holdingright = false;
   bool resetballspeed = false;

   public Game1()
   {
      graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
      Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

      graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 760; 
      graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 620; 
  }

  protected override void Initialize()
  {
      random = new Random();
      linje_speed.X = 6f;
      linjeliten_speed.X = 6f;
      boll_speed.X = random.Next(-1, 1);
      boll_speed.Y = 7f;

      sr = new StreamReader("highscore.txt");
      highscore = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
      sr.Close();

      base.Initialize();
  }

  protected override void LoadContent()
  {
      spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
      spritefont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("Fonts/Myfont");
      linje_texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Pics/linje-lång");
      linjeliten_texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Pics/linje");
      boll_texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Pics/boll");
      blockgrön_texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Pics/block-grön");
      blockröd_texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Pics/block-röd");
      gameover_texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Pics/GameOver");
      linje_rect = new Rectangle((Window.ClientBounds.Width - linje_texture.Width) / 2, 580, linje_texture.Width, linje_texture.Height);
      linjeliten_rect = new Rectangle((Window.ClientBounds.Width - linjeliten_texture.Width) / 2, 580, linjeliten_texture.Width, linjeliten_texture.Height);
      boll_rect = new Rectangle((Window.ClientBounds.Width - boll_texture.Width) / 2, 556, boll_texture.Width, boll_texture.Height);
      gameover_rect = new Rectangle((Window.ClientBounds.Width / 2) - (gameover_texture.Width / 2), (Window.ClientBounds.Height / 2) - gameover_texture.Height / 2, gameover_texture.Width, gameover_texture.Height);

      block.Add(blockgrön_rect);
      block2.Add(blockröd_rect);
      for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++)
      {
          for (int g = 1; g < 13; g++)
          {
              block2.Add(new Rectangle((g * 63) - 60, (i * 20), blockröd_texture.Width, blockröd_texture.Height));
          }
      }
      for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
      {
          for (int g = 1; g < 13; g++)
          {
              block.Add(new Rectangle((g * 63) - 60, (i * 20) + 20, blockgrön_texture.Width, blockgrön_texture.Height));
          }
      }
  }

  protected override void UnloadContent()
  {
      // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
  }

  protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
  {
      if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
      {
          if (poang == highscore)
          {
              sw = new StreamWriter("highscore.txt");
              sw.WriteLine(poang);
              sw.Close();
          }
          Exit();
      }
      if (Start == true) 
      {
          boll_rect.X += (int)boll_speed.X;
          boll_rect.Y += (int)boll_speed.Y;
      }

      if (Start == false)
      {
          boll_rect.X = linje_rect.X + ((linje_texture.Width / 2) - (boll_texture.Width / 2)); //how the ball condition is to the long line
          boll_rect.X = linjeliten_rect.X + ((linjeliten_texture.Width / 2) - (boll_texture.Width / 2)); //the same but ball condition to small line
      }
      if (boll_rect.X > Window.ClientBounds.Width - boll_texture.Width || boll_rect.X < 0) 
          boll_speed.X *= -1;

      if (boll_rect.Y > Window.ClientBounds.Height - boll_texture.Height || boll_rect.Y < 0) 
          boll_speed.Y *= -1;

      if (boll_rect.Y > Window.ClientBounds.Height - boll_texture.Height) 
      {
          liv -= 1;
          Start = false;
          boll_rect.X = (Window.ClientBounds.Width - boll_texture.Width) / 2; 
          boll_rect.Y = 556; 
          linje_rect.X = (Window.ClientBounds.Width - linje_texture.Width) / 2;
          linje_rect.Y = 580; 
          linjeliten_rect.X = (Window.ClientBounds.Width - linjeliten_texture.Width) / 2; 
          linjeliten_rect.Y = 580; 
      }

      KeyboardState ks = Keyboard.GetState();
      if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left)) 
      {
          linje_rect.X -= (int)linje_speed.X; 
          linjeliten_rect.X -= (int)linjeliten_speed.X;
          holdingleft = true;
      }
      else if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right)) 
      {
          linje_rect.X += (int)linje_speed.X;
          linjeliten_rect.X += (int)linjeliten_speed.X;
          holdingright = true;
      }
      else if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space)) 
      {
          Start = true;
      }

      if (ks.Equals(new KeyboardState()))
      {
          resetballspeed = true;
      }

      if (linje_rect.X > Window.ClientBounds.Width - linje_texture.Width) 
          linje_rect.X = (Window.ClientBounds.Width - linje_texture.Width);

      if (linjeliten_rect.X > Window.ClientBounds.Width - linjeliten_texture.Width) 
          linjeliten_rect.X = (Window.ClientBounds.Width - linjeliten_texture.Width);

      if (linje_rect.X < 0) 
          linje_rect.X = 0;

      if (linjeliten_rect.X < 0) 
          linjeliten_rect.X = 0;

      if (linje_rect.Intersects(boll_rect)) 
      {
          boll_speed.Y *= -1;
          boll_rect.Y += (int)boll_speed.Y;
          if (holdingleft == true)
          {
              boll_speed.X -= 2;
          }
          else if (holdingright == true)
          {
              boll_speed.X += 2;
          }
          else if (resetballspeed == true)
          {
              boll_speed.X = 1;
          }
      }

      if (linjeliten_rect.Intersects(boll_rect))
      {
          boll_speed.Y *= -1;
          boll_rect.Y += (int)boll_speed.Y;
          if (holdingleft == true)
          {
              boll_speed.X -= 1;
          }
          else if (holdingright == true)
          {
              boll_speed.X += 1;
          }
          else if (resetballspeed == true)
          {
              boll_speed.X = 1;
          }
      }

      for (int j = 1; j < block.Count; j++) 
      {
          if (boll_rect.Intersects(block[j])) 
          {
              boll_speed.Y *= -1;
              poang += 1;
              block.RemoveAt(j); 
              if (poang > highscore)
              {
                  highscore++;
              }
          }
      }
      for (int k = 1; k < block2.Count; k++) 
      {
          if (boll_rect.Intersects(block2[k])) 
          {
              boll_speed.Y *= -1;
              poang += 5;
              block2.RemoveAt(k); 
              if (poang > highscore)
              {
                  highscore += 5;
              }
          }
      }

      holdingleft = false;
      holdingright = false;


      base.Update(gameTime);
  }

  protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
  {
      GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

      spriteBatch.Begin();
      if (liv > 0)
      {
          if (poang < 10)
          {
              spriteBatch.Draw(linje_texture, linje_rect, Color.White);
          }
          else if (poang > 9)
          {
              spriteBatch.Draw(linjeliten_texture, linjeliten_rect, Color.White);
          }
          spriteBatch.Draw(boll_texture, boll_rect, Color.White);
          spriteBatch.DrawString(spritefont, "Lives left: " + liv, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
          spriteBatch.DrawString(spritefont, "Points: " + poang, new Vector2(350, 0), Color.White);
          spriteBatch.DrawString(spritefont, "Highscore: " + highscore, new Vector2(660, 0), Color.White);
          foreach (Rectangle g in block)
          {
              spriteBatch.Draw(blockgrön_texture, g, Color.White);
          }
          foreach (Rectangle t in block2)
          {
              spriteBatch.Draw(blockröd_texture, t, Color.White);
          }
      }
      else if (liv == 0)
      {
          spriteBatch.Draw(gameover_texture, gameover_rect, Color.White);
          if (poang == highscore)
          {
              sw = new StreamWriter("highscore.txt");
              sw.WriteLine(poang);
              sw.Close();
          }
      }

      spriteBatch.End();

      base.Draw(gameTime);
  }
  }
  ```

**Having trouble with these parts:**

```
        for (int j = 1; j < block.Count; j++) //loopar igenom alla block
        {
            if (boll_rect.Intersects(block[j])) //om bollen träffar rutorna
            {
                boll_speed.Y *= -1;
                poang += 1;
                block.RemoveAt(j); //tar bort gröna blocket man träffar
                if (poang > 9)
                {
                    linje_rect.Width = 60;
                }
                if (poang > highscore)
                {
                    highscore++;
                }
            }
        }
```

---

```
        for (int k = 1; k < block2.Count; k++) 
        {
            if (boll_rect.Intersects(block2[k])) 
            {
                boll_speed.Y *= -1;
                poang += 5;
                block2.RemoveAt(k); 
                if (poang > highscore)
                {
                    highscore += 5;
                }
                block2.RemoveAt(k); 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `highscore++;` with `highscore = poang;`

and `highscore += 5;` with `highscore = poang;`

to avoid mismatches between highscore and current score.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! Haha didn't think about that simple fix :)